# Nodemailer not working on mobile phone>> (Next js web + nodemailer with next js api)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, nodemailer

I made a simple website with a contact form. The website is made by next 10, react 17, and nodemailer. The contact form works fine on the laptop (Chrome, Firefox) but on mobile phone, does not work. The message sent by contact form does not send to Gmail inbox. Here is the code.
React-Hook-form was used also.

```
// contactform.js
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import { toast } from 'react-toastify';
import { useState } from 'react';
import Loader from "react-loader-spinner";

export default function ContactForm() {
   const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
   const { register, handleSubmit, errors, reset } = useForm();
   
   const onSubmitForm = async (values) => {
      let config = {
         method: "POST",
         headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
         },
         body: JSON.stringify(values)
      };
      
      let data;
      
      try {
         setIsLoading(true);
         const res = await fetch("/api/contact", config);
         data = await res.json();
         
         if (data.success === "ok") {
            reset();
            setIsLoading(false);
            return toast.success(data.message, {
               position: toast.POSITION.TOP_CENTER
            });
         }
         if (data.success === "fail") {
            reset();
            setIsLoading(false);
            return toast.warn(data.error, {
               position: toast.POSITION.TOP_CENTER
             });
         }
        
      } catch (err) {
         reset();
         return toast.error(data.error, {
            position: toast.POSITION.TOP_CENTER
         });
      }
   };
   
   return (
      <div className="relative flex flex-wrap justify-center lg:-mt-64 -mt-48">
         <div className="w-full lg:w-6/12 px-4">
            <div className="relative flex flex-col min-w-0 break-words w-full mb-6 shadow-lg rounded-lg bg-gray-300">
               <form
                  className="flex-auto p-5 lg:p-10"
                  onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmitForm)}
               >
                  <h4 className="text-2xl font-semibold">
                     Start Your Story
                     <span className="block sm:inline-block ml-1">
                        With Us
                           
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" className="w-4 h-4 mb-3 ml-2 inline rounded-ful text-yellow-500 animate-ping font-bold">
                           <path strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" strokeWidth={2} d="M11.049 2.927c.3-.921 1.603-.921 1.902 0l1.519 4.674a1 1 0 00.95.69h4.915c.969 0 1.371 1.24.588 1.81l-3.976 2.888a1 1 0 00-.363 1.118l1.518 4.674c.3.922-.755 1.688-1.538 1.118l-3.976-2.888a1 1 0 00-1.176 0l-3.976 2.888c-.783.57-1.838-.197-1.538-1.118l1.518-4.674a1 1 0 00-.363-1.118l-3.976-2.888c-.784-.57-.38-1.81.588-1.81h4.914a1 1 0 00.951-.69l1.519-4.674z" />
                        </svg>
                     </span>
                     
                  </h4>
                  <p className="leading-relaxed mt-1 mb-4 text-gray-600">
                        무엇이든 물어보세요! 
                  </p>
                  <p className="leading-relaxed -mt-3 mb-4 text-gray-600">
                     24시간 안에 답장을 해드리겠습니다. 
                  </p>
                  <div className="relative w-full mb-3 mt-8">
                     <label
                     className="block uppercase text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mb-2"
                     htmlFor="full-name"
                     >
                     이름
                     </label>
                     <input
                        type="text"
                        name="name"
                        ref={register({
                           required: {
                              value: true,
                              message: '이름을 입력 하셔여 합니다!'
                           }
                        })}
                        className={`px-3 py-3 placeholder-gray-400 text-gray-700 bg-white rounded text-sm shadow focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline w-full ${errors.name ? 'ring-2 ring-red-500': null}`}
                        placeholder="Full Name"
                        style={{ transition: "all .15s ease" }}
                     />
                     <span className="text-red-400 text-sm py-2">
                        {errors?.name?.message}
                     </span>
                  </div>

                  <div className="relative w-full mb-3">
                     <label
                        className="block uppercase text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mb-2"
                        htmlFor="email"
                     >
                        이메일
                     </label>
                     <input
                        type="text"
                        name="email"
                        ref={register({
                           required: {
                              value: true,
                              message: '이메일 주소를 입력 하셔여 합니다!'
                           },
                           minLength: {
                              value: 8,
                              message: '정확한 이메일 주소를 입력 바랍니다!'
                           },
                           maxLength: {
                              value: 30,
                              message: '정확한 이메일 주소를 입력 바랍니다!'
                           },
                           pattern: {
                              value: /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,}$/i,
                              message: "이메일 형식이 틀립니다. 다시 입력 해주세요! "
                              }
                        })}
                        className={`px-3 py-3 placeholder-gray-400 text-gray-700 bg-white rounded text-sm shadow focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline w-full ${errors.email ? 'ring-2 ring-red-500': null}`}
                        placeholder="Email"
                        style={{ transition: "all .15s ease" }}
                     />
                     <span className="text-red-400 text-sm py-2">
                        {errors?.email?.message}
                     </span>
                  </div>

                  <div className="relative w-full mb-3">
                     <label
                        className="block uppercase text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mb-2"
                        htmlFor="message"
                     >
                        메시지
                     </label>
                     <textarea
                        rows={4}
                        cols={80}
                        name="message"
                        ref={register({
                           required: {
                              value: true,
                              message: '메세지를 입력 하셔여 합니다!'
                           },
                           minLength: {
                              value: 20,
                              message: '메세지는 20자 이상이여야 합니다!'
                           },
                        })}
                        className={`px-3 py-3 placeholder-gray-400 text-gray-700 bg-white rounded text-sm shadow focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline w-full ${errors.message ? 'ring-2 ring-red-500': null}`}
                        placeholder="Type a message..."
                     />
                     <span className="text-red-400 text-sm py-2">
                        {errors?.message?.message}
                     </span>
                  </div>
                     
                  <div className="text-center mt-6">
                     <button
                        className="bg-gray-900 text-white active:bg-gray-700 text-sm font-bold uppercase px-8 py-3 rounded shadow-lg hover:shadow-lg outline-none focus:outline-none mr-1 mb-1 transition duration-300"
                        type="submit"
                     >
                        <span>{isLoading ? ( <Loader
                           type="TailSpin"
                           color="#00BFFF"
                           height={15}
                           width={15}
                           timeout={3000} 
                           className="inline-block mr-3"
                        />) : null}</span>
                        보내기
                     </button>
                  </div>
               </form>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   );
}
```

```
// /api/contact.js
import nodemailer from 'nodemailer';
import Cors from 'cors';
require('dotenv').config();

const cors = Cors({
   methods: ['POST'],
   origin: 'https://www.veritas101.com',
   optionsSuccessStatus: 200
});

function runMiddleware(req, res, fn) {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     fn(req, res, (result) => {
       if (result instanceof Error) {
         return reject(result)
       }
       return resolve(result)
     })
   })
 }

export default async function handler(req, res) {
   await runMiddleware(req, res, cors);
   
   if (!req.body) {
      return res.status(400).end();
   }
   
   const { name, email, message } = req.body;
   
   const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
      port: 465,
      secure: true,
      auth: {
         user: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_USER_EMAIL,
         pass: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_USER_PASS
      }
   });
   
   const mailData = {
      from: email,
      to: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_USER_EMAIL,
      subject: `Contact form submission from ${name}`,
      html: `<h3>You have a new contact from submission</h3><br/>
      <h4><strong>Name: </strong>${name}</h4><br/>
      <h4><strong>Email: </strong>${email}</h4><br/>
      <h4><strong>Message:<br/> </strong>${message}</h4><br/>
      `
   };
  
   transporter.verify((error, _)=> {
      console.error(error);
   });
   
   const emailSending = await transporter.sendMail(mailData);
   
   if (!emailSending.messageId) {
      return res.status(400).json({ error: "problem" , success: "fail" });
   } else {
      return res.status(200).json({ message: "success", success: "ok" });
   }
   
}
```